# Layout Text with Drawable excat and performant

Tags: android, layout, textview, drawable

How can I layout a Text with an icon exactly like this:

[image]

I did it with this Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="64dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgIcon"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:src="@drawable/delete_icon" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtLabel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:text="xxx" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

But the [Android guide](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html#Lint) says: *Use compound drawables - A LinearLayout which contains an ImageView and a TextView can be more efficiently handled as a compound drawable.*
I have tried, but I couldn't find the layout parameters (size for the image, different paddings for image and text) that I need.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtLabel"
    android:layout_width="64dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
    android:duplicateParentState="true"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/delete_icon"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:drawablePadding="8dp"
    android:text="xxx" />
```

Here is the result (left with RelativeLayout, right with compound drawable):

[image]

If there is a better standard component which provides the necessary parameters, it's acceptable, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to do the same.
I got this result (please note that the image has an "optical square", which is smaller than the physical image size):

[image]

I'm using my favourite method: the compound drawable.

But:

1 - I prepared some images at different resolutions, so that 32*32 is referred to a standard mdpi (160dpi) resolution, and scaling at different resolutions (xxhdpi is 96*96 px wide and tall)-
2 - I placed these images in the corresponding drawable folders (drawable-ldpi to drawable-xxhdpi).
3 - I corrected the layout a bit, to match.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:padding="0dp"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtLabel"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/delete_icon"
        android:drawablePadding="4dp"
        android:text="XXX"
        android:textSize="12sp"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I used all caps letters to better see the spacing between the text and the drawable.
Does it fit your needs?